# Removing a file from an earlier commit?

Tags: git, github, version-control

By mistake I have done `git commit` of a big file in local Git Repo and pushed in remote(it got pushed as size was less than 100Mb though very large).

After that commit, I did many other commits(so lost track where I committed the large file).

On `git push` I got an error that the file is > 100 Mb(as the file size had increased) so it's unable to push.

After I got the error I did `git rm` on that file.

Now, when I do `git push` again the same error is still coming.

My approach is to first retrieve the `git rm` file(using `git checkout commit#wherefilewasnotdeleted`) then remove the file from the commit(using `git reset -- soft Head`) ?

I am trying the above approach still it's not getting out of the code that I push when I do `git push`?

Kindly suggest what to do?

Comment: If the big commit is already on the published remote branch, you will need to rewrite the remote history.  Please see if you can do this, and update your question.

Comment: @Coderaemon If your branch is a working branch that started from master and is supposed to be merged to master eventually, use `git rebase -i origin/master` to rewrite all the commits from the beginning of the branch, and edit or delete the commit containing the large file.

Answer (score 2):

You should use this tool:

https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/

It the prefect tool for this kind of task

> #### BFG Repo-Cleaner
>
> an alternative to git-filter-branch.
>
> The BFG is a simpler, faster alternative to git-filter-branch for cleansing **bad data** out of your Git repository history:
>
> - Removing Crazy Big Files
> - Removing Passwords, Credentials & other Private data

#### Examples (from the official site)

> In all these examples bfg is an alias for java -jar bfg.jar.

```
# Delete all files named 'id_rsa' or 'id_dsa' :
bfg --delete-files id_{dsa,rsa}  my-repo.git
```